# Las demas Opciones deben desmarcarse - CheckBox - Winform

Tags: visual-studio

Tengo un proyecto el cual me pide seleccionar un tipo de canal de Ventas y donde ya genere un If por los cuatro checkbox en una Funcion de Validación  juntos, pero en Enunciado de mi proyecto me pide, que si en el caso de que el Usuario seleccione la opción de "TODOS", las demás opciones deben desmarcarse

Paso la parte del codigo que genere

```
Function DatosValidos() As Boolean   
 If chkMinorista.Checked = False And chkMayorista.Checked = False And chkExportación.Checked = False And chkTODOS.Checked = False Then
            MessageBox.Show("Debe escoger uno o más Canales de Ventas", Me.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            chkMinorista.Focus()  
            Return False  
 End If  
  Return True  
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Las propiedades de los objetos pueden ser controladas durante la ejecución de tu aplicación. Para conseguir lo que deseas, puedes intentar añadir una condición IF que cheque si la opcion TODOS está seleccionada. Si es así, desmarcarías las otras opciones volviendo False su propiedad 'Checked':

```
    Function DatosValidos() As Boolean   
     If chkMinorista.Checked = False And chkMayorista.Checked = False And chkExportación.Checked = False And chkTODOS.Checked = False Then
                MessageBox.Show("Debe escoger uno o más Canales de Ventas", Me.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                chkMinorista.Focus()  
                Return False  
     End If  

    If chkTODOS.Checked = True Then
    chkMinorista.Checked = False
    chkMayorista.Checked = False
    chkExportación.Checked = False
    End If

      Return True  
    End Function
```